# How to remove unwanted edge artifacts at borders of Cycles-rendered images?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts, denoise

I'm tried rendering [cubic skybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_(video_games)) with a procedural **Sky Texture** in **Blender** via **Cycles** and unexpectedly encountered artifacts at boundaries of rendered square images (which a skybox is then assembled in bitmap editor). Each square image has a noticeable artifacts at border, especially in darker areas of the image (as screen seen).

[image]

You can reproduce this problem in **Blender** in 3 minutes:

1. Create general empty scene (delete **cube** and **light**)
2. Set up **World** **Shading nodes** with **Sky texture** as screen seen.
3. Place **Camera** at zero position **(0,0,0)** and angles **(90, 0, 90)**.
4. Set **Camera** properties Lens unit to Field of View, **FOV = 90 degrees**.
5. Set **Output** format properties resolution 512x512 pixels (or 1024x1024 - any square image for cubic skybox).
6. Render **Image #1**, save on disk.
7. Rotate **Camera** to angles **(90, 0, 0)**.
8. Render **Image #2**, save on disk.
9. Open any bitmap editor (Photoshop, Gimp etc) and make common wide picture from square **Images #1 and #2** (place them side to side).
10. Check border between **Image #1 and #2**.
11. In my case always seen artifacts (1-2 pixels width dark distortion edges) at boundaries each square image as screen seen.

Can anyone check this problem and tell how to fix in the Cycles rendering settings to remove such artifacts at borders of square images?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cube, smooth shaded, with the following shader, and bake it:

[image]

Using "normal" instead of "reflection" should work the same, I think. Same thing if you subdivide the cube to make it spherical.

But that does not seems to matter as normals are smoothed.

Comment: Sorry @lemon, when I returned to creating skyboxes I discovered that your variant of baking skybox still had problem with artifacts on the edges of baked cubemap images. Please see my answer.

Comment: no problem, it is normal Nazar

Answer (score 0):

When I returned to creating skyboxes I discovered that **@lemon** variant of baking skybox still had problem with artifacts on the edges of baked cubemap images.

The artifacts are same: dark distortion edges at boundaries between the render and the empty area of the image (as screen seen).

But at least I found one solution (far from optimal, unfortunately):

If you uncheck **Denoise** option, artifacts around the edges of the baked cubemap won't appear. I've tried different params of Blender's built-in denoisers, but they all add such artifacts. Perhaps there is another way, because then for a clean cubemap of real complex skybox scene you will need much more baking time with a significant amount of "Max Samples" for Cycles render when **Denoise** OFF.

I don't want to mark my answer as correct because instead of a few minutes I have to wait whole hours of baking with a much worse cubemap quality (lots of pixelated noise without the denoiser). I also believe that the denoiser should not degrade the cubemap with edge artifacts.

***So, is there another better way?***
[image]